# Differences between the various translations for "but", "however"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, difference

I'd like to know the regularly used Italian translations for the words *but* and *however*, or the German *aber* and *jedoch*.

Here's what https://dict.leo.org/italienisch-deutsch is saying:

[image]

[image]

These are about 16 translations in total, and there are only three translations matching between *aber* and *jedoch* (*eppure*, *sennonché* and *comunque*).

- Which translations are frequently used, and which ones are rare?
- Are there semantic differences between some of them?
- Why are some of them classified as adjectives or adverbs? What would be a correct use of *invece* as an adjective or adverb?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: The only word of all these which can be an adjective is "stesso", but then it wouldn't mean "however". I immagine that refers to the adverbial use of the expression "lo stesso" that maybe in some contexts can be translated as "however".

Comment: @Charo I see. But why are there adverbial translations of "but" or "however"? In my understanding, all those words should be conjuctions, not adverbs. So I'm still looking for an example of an adverbial use of words like *invece*, *poi*, *pure* and *tuttavia*.

Comment: I know I am becoming an old grouch, but monolingual dictionaries and thesauri have been invented (centuries ago) *precisely* to answer this kind of questions. Asking them rather than consulting a reference book is like going on a SE site to ask how many inhabitants has Sweden rather than looking it up. If *after* looking it up one still has some doubts, *that's* the sense of this site, not sifting through 16 random words grabbed from the net.

Comment: @DaG You are of course right, I could look that up in a monolingual dictionary, to the degree my knowledge of Italian allows this. Please note however that I didn't ask "Please explain to me, for each of the 16 words, what it means and when it's used". The intention of this question is to get an overview of the differences, and to get an example of an adverbial use of such a word.

Comment: @Bass:  In this particular case, "lo stesso" has the meaning of "anyway"or "nevertheless", which are adverbs. For instance, the meaning of the sentence "Non mi hanno invitato, ma ci andrò **lo stesso**" (which I took from WordReference) is "They haven't invited me, but I'm going there anyway".

Comment: Even if, in my opinion, this is an interesting question, I think it would be quite hard to provide an answer. Not only because it would imply explaining 16 Italian words, but also because it involves translation without an specific context, which is something really difficult. In addition, I think it also involves translating to English or to German (and I'm afraid we are no experts about this in this site).

Comment: For instance, in my previous comment I wrote the sentence "Non mi hanno invitato, ma ci andrò lo stesso", but if I want to include it as an example in an answer, I would have to see if there is a good English translation that contains the word "however" (something about I'm not really sure).

Comment: And, according to my Webster's dictionary, "however" can also be an adverb or a conjunction. For instance, "*We have not yet won; however, we shall keep trying*" (here "however" is an adverb), but "*Arrange your hours however you like*" (here "however" is a conjunction).

Comment: @Charo, Slight correction, if I may; I think those should be swapped. "However" the conjunction is in the first sentence (since it separates the two clauses on not winning and trying) and "however" the adverb is in the second sentence because it modifies the verb arrange.

Comment: @Marco: These examples are not mine: I copied them from Webster's Universal College Dictionary. But you can have reason, anyway.

Comment: To answer your first question, [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/) is really useful. If you search "invece" or "poi", for instance, you will see that these words are marked as "FO", which stands for ["fondamentale"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6). This means that these words are very frequently used. But if you search "peraltro", in this case you will find the mark ["AU"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6). The occurrences of words with this mark constitute a 6% approximately of the occurrences of words in all written or spoken texts

Comment: Finally, if you search "nonpertanto", which can also be written "non pertanto", you will see the mark "BU", which stands for "basso uso". This means that this word is rare.

Comment: Thanks guys. If you think the question is not fit for this site, you can vote to close it.